# ios memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, nsxmlparser

I have a method that sets up NSXMLParser with the correct data that I am pretty sure is causing a memory leak.

This is my first time using instriments to try and solve a memory leak and have got it down to the offending method..

by looking at the response caller value in instruments memory leak testing.

I am hoping you can tell me where the memory leak is here... because I release both myDataArray and parser... im just not sure where I am going wrong.. do I need to assign them nil also?

```
- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    [myDataArray release]; // clears array for next time it is used.
    myDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //parserData passed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts the parsing process 

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; // starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    [parser release];
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have made the changes to my application and when I run it on the simulator I do not get any memory leak errors..

however if I run it on my phone  get this in the console...

```
2011-10-19 11:22:05.673 code[1299:707] -[__NSCFType section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b9b80
2011-10-19 11:22:05.683 code[1299:707] CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: -[__NSCFType section]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b9b80
2011-10-19 11:22:07.949 code[1299:707] -[__NSCFType row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b9b80
2011-10-19 11:22:07.951 code[1299:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b9b80'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x35e9e8b3 0x366e61e5 0x35ea1acb 0x35ea0939 0x35dfb680 0x334a76cf 0x3353c713 0x30fd5 0x3352cd69 0x335a60ab 0x35cc32ab 0x35e72a57 0x35e726bd 0x35e71293 0x35df44e5 0x35df43ad 0x30fa4fed 0x334a7dc7 0x272f 0x26d8)
```

Comment: does initWithData retain an instance of parserData?

Comment: @Wolfert It does, but the release is handled by NSXMLParser when it deallocs. The rule is that if you retain (take ownership) you must release it.

Comment: I guess it dose, as I am not clearing that at any time.. as I don't know how to clear it..

Comment: asif you've released the parser to early, maybe doing it in the dealloc method would help?

Comment: okay I will try that and see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in the .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myDataArray

.m

@synthesize myDataArray

in the method...

- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    self.myDataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //parserData passed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts the parsing process 

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; // starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    [parser release];
}
```

Comment: @C.Johns No specific reason really, you just have to initialize to the capacity you are likely to use, it will double every time that capacity is met. But if you initialize high, it won't have to double as many times, which is more efficient.

Comment: right. cool.. it defiantly helped with the memory allocation being alot smaller.. however I am still having an issue with my application.. I have added it to my question if you could check it out and let me know what you think it is that would be a huge help.. thank you so far for the help you have given me.